# Variation of modulus of a complex number?

Tags: complex-numbers, calculus-of-variations

I want to find a rule to link the variation of the square of the modulus of a complex number, $\delta \lvert z \rvert^2$, to the variation of the complex number, $\delta z$. Or are the following relations correct?

1. $$\delta \lvert z \rvert^2=2 \lvert z\rvert \delta \lvert z\rvert=2 \lvert z\rvert \delta \lvert z\rvert,$$
2. $$\delta\lvert z \rvert=\lvert \delta z \rvert.$$

Many thanks！

Comment: Is the first $\delta \lvert z \rvert^2=2 \lvert z\rvert \delta \lvert z\rvert=2 \lvert z\rvert \lvert \delta z\rvert,$

Comment: Hi @Nosrati, that may be the heart of my question :)

Comment: Hi, I meant $\delta$ is inside of modulus?

Comment: I see @Nosrati, could u plz explain more? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all $z\in\Bbb C\setminus\{0\}$, $$\frac{\partial\lvert z\rvert}{\partial z}=\frac{\overline z}{2\lvert z\rvert}\\ \frac{\partial\lvert z\rvert}{\partial \overline z}=\frac{z}{2\lvert z\rvert}$$

The aforementioned are [Wirtinger's derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirtinger_derivatives). Wirtinger's derivatives of a function $f:\Bbb C\to\Bbb C$ at a point $a$ have this property: if $(z_1,z_2)$ is a pair of complex numbers such that $$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac1{\lvert h\rvert}\left(f(a+h)-f(a)-hz_1-\overline hz_2\right)=0,$$ then $z_1=\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}(a)$ and $z_2=\frac{\partial f}{\partial \overline z}(a)$.

Comment: Very fast reply and very helpful @Saucy O'Path! Could I write: $\frac{\partial (\lvert z \rvert^2)}{\partial z}=2\lvert z \rvert \frac{\partial \lvert z \rvert}{\partial z}=2\lvert z \rvert \frac{\bar{z}}{2\lvert z \rvert}=\bar{z}$. Thus, $\delta \lvert z \rvert^2=\bar{z} \delta z$

Comment: It is true that $\frac{\partial \lvert z\rvert^2}{\partial z}=\overline z$ and $\frac{\partial \lvert z\rvert^2}{\partial \overline z}=z$.